# Can setsockopt() and gethostbyname() be blocked for my case?

Tags: sockets

I use some cross-platform library (it's written in Haskell but it does not matter) and the library has a function (`setInterface`) which performs 2 C runtime calls:

1. `gethostbyname()`
2. `setsockopt()`

It's not a question about Haskell and its libraries but about these 2 C runtime calls.

The first function in my case gets a string which is IP address. Always. This is my use case. The second one - `setsockopt()` sets `IP_MULTICAST_LOOP` option.

And I have to support 3 OSes: Windows, Mac, Linux. So, the question includes:

1. **can `gethostbyname()` be blocked in my case?**
2. **can `setsockopt()` be blocked in my case?**

Or with different words, how fast can they be executed?

For me, it's more important the `setsockopt()` because I can rewrite this `setInterface` so to avoid `gethostbyname()` call at all, but I don't know how fast will be executed `setsockopt()` in my case.

For my part, I checked the documentation, from one point of view `gethostbyname()` calls DNS. But I don't know will it call DNS for IP? And I have not ideas about `setsockopt()` - I used to think that it is not blocked call, but from another point of view I checked both for Windows and I see that they both can return `WSAEINPROGRESS`:

```
WSAEINPROGRESS        A blocking Windows Sockets 1.1 call is in progress, or the
                      service provide is still processing a callback function.
```

Maybe it would be more correct not to suggest about OSes implementations and to think about them that they always can be blocked (in Windows, Mac, Linux)?

Comment: `gethostbyname()` is old and deprecated, use `getaddrinfo()` instead.  If your input is always an IP, you can specify the `AI_NUMERICHOST` flag to force DNS to be skipped and just parse the input as-is.

Comment: `setsockopt()` has nothing to block on except a temporary lock on the socket data. No network activity except in the case of multicast group joins or leaves.